# Object logs null instead of calendar data

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a HTML service application that asks for a date to attend a class. When you select a date it gives you a checkbox, class title, and class description. Your suppose to check the classes you want to attend and then click the attend button to log the data. I get the call to log because it logs something but it is always 'null' and not the event selected.

Here is my code.gs:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index.html').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}

function listEvents(dateSelected) {

  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('CalendarID').getEventsForDay(new Date(dateSelected));
  if (calendar[0] == null) {
    var text = 'No classes for this date';
    return text;
  }
  else {
    var text = '<form id="eventsForm">';
    for (var i=0; i < calendar.length; i++) {
      text += "<input type='checkbox' name=";
      text += i+1;
      text += " value=";
      text += calendar[i].getTitle();
      text += ">";
      text += calendar[i].getTitle();
      text += ' - ';
      text += calendar[i].getDescription();
      text += '<br>';
    }
    text += "<input type='button' value='Attend' onclick='google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(test).processForm(this.parentnode)' />";
    text += "</form>";
    return text; 
  }
}

function processForm(x) {
  Logger.log(x);
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="container" >
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to the sign up page</h1>
      <p>Please select a date for the class you'd like to attend below.</p>
      <p>Click Here: <input type="text" name="date" id="datepicker" /><p> 
    </div>
</div>
<div id='test'></div>

<script>
$("#datepicker").datepicker();
$("#datepicker").on("change", function () {
var dateSelected = $(this).val()
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).listEvents(dateSelected);
});

function onSuccess(eventText) {
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=eventText;
}

</script>
```

When you click the attend button it goes to processFrom in code.gs and logs but as I said it only logs the date/time and 'null' instead of the class. I'm just trying to check that I get something back so that I can send the classes people check to a spreadsheet to show who is coming. Any Ideas on how to get the form to send back the correct data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you'll see it you are going to be stunned!
rename "this.parentnode" for "this.parentNode"

here your script working:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index.html').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}

function listEvents(dateSelected) {
  Logger.log("dateSeleted: "+dateSelected);
  var selDate = new Date(dateSelected);
  Logger.log(selDate);
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('CalendarID').getEventsForDay(new Date(dateSelected));
  if (calendar[0] == null) {
    var text = 'No classes for this date';
    return text;
  }
  else {
    var text = '<form id="eventsForm">';
    for (var i=0; i < calendar.length; i++) {
      text += "<input type='checkbox' name=";
      text += i+1;
      text += " value=";
      text += calendar[i].getTitle();
      text += ">";
      text += calendar[i].getTitle();
      text += ' - ';
      text += calendar[i].getDescription();
      text += '<br>';
    }
    text += "<input type='button' value='Attend' onclick='google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(test).processForm(this.parentNode)' />";
    text += "</form>";
    return text; 
  }
}

function processForm(x) {
  Logger.log("x: "+JSON.stringify(x));
}
```

this happen to me too, I hate when I do this kind of error and I search for hours a solution.
Good luck for the rest of your code!

Comment: Harold, I know we aren't suppose to reply with this (as per stackoverflow rules) but: THANK YOU. Holy Moley I have been searching for this for two days. Thanks again.